# Match two JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two nested json files like this:

```
$.getJSON('data/user.json', function(data) {
  $.getJSON('data/food.json', function(data) {
  ...
  });
});
```

This is a sample of user.json:

```
[
    {
        "userDetails": {
            "id": 27080
        },
        "Items": [
            {
                "ItemDetails": {
                    "idProduct": 1420
                },
                "quantity": 1,
                "name": "test1"
            },
            {
                "ItemDetails": {
                    "idProduct": 1959
                },
                "quantity": 5,
                "name": "test2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is a sample of food.json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1420,
        "name": "test1",
        "price": 12.5,
        "tags": [
            "cold",
            "ice"
        ],
        "proteins": 50,
        "ch": 60
    }
]
```

The problem is:
I need to match idProduct of user.json WITH id of food.json and print data.
(idProduct can occur more than once)

Comment: user json is not valid

Comment: You are also overwriting the `data` parameter in the inner anonymous function.

Comment: maybe I forgot some ',' in user.json, but it is valid, and i can get all data from both jsons, but i don't know how to connect them :/

Comment: paste your json in http://jsonlint.com/ to better understand the json error

Comment: get them seperately and save the results for later comparison instead of having the first getJSON call the second after it finishes.

Comment: @Ficho check out my answer, i tested it out with the small JSON snippets you gave and it works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i will do first is to fetch the two json files and save them locally.

```
   $.getJSON('data/user.json', function(data) { ... => into user
   $.getJSON('data/food.json', function(data) { ... => into food
```

Now, assuming that user and food have both valid JSON objects. I would do a small function to retrieve/print a food object given an ID.

I will be using a small caching object, in case the files are big and do not want to do a full loop if you already fetched the item before.

Note: I am using here [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) fir simplification.

```
var food_cache = {};

function print_or_retreive_food(id) {

    var food_item;

    if (_.has(food_cache, id)) {
        food_item = food_cache.id;
    } else {
        _.each(food, function(item) {
            if (item.id == id) {
                food_cache[id] = item;
                food_item = item;
            }
        });
    }

    // alternatively if it is printing then do a console.log or whatever you like
    return food_item;

}
```

Now, what you need to do is loop the user object and call the function.

```
_.each(user, function(userItem){
    if (_.has(userItem, "Items")) {
        _.each(userItem.Items, function(item){
            print_or_retreive_food(item.ItemDetails.idProduct);
        });
    }
});
```

Putting it all together:

```js
var user = [
    {
        "userDetails": {
            "id": 27080
        },
        "Items": [
            {
                "ItemDetails": {
                    "idProduct": 1420
                },
                "quantity": 1,
                "name": "test1"
            },
            {
                "ItemDetails": {
                    "idProduct": 1959
                },
                "quantity": 5,
                "name": "test2"
            }
        ]
    }
]

var food = [
    {
        "id": 1420,
        "name": "test1",
        "price": 12.5,
        "tags": [
            "cold",
            "ice"
        ],
        "proteins": 50,
        "ch": 60
    }
]

var food_cache = {};

function print_or_retreive_food(id) {

    var food_item;

    if (_.has(food_cache, id)) {
        food_item = food_cache.id;
    } else {
        _.each(food, function(item) {
            if (item.id == id) {
                food_cache[id] = item;
                food_item = item;
            }
        });
    }

    // alternatively if it is printing then do a console.log or whatever you like
   $('body').append('<p>' + JSON.stringify(food_item) + '</p>');

}

_.each(user, function(userItem){
    if (_.has(userItem, "Items")) {
        _.each(userItem.Items, function(item){
            print_or_retreive_food(item.ItemDetails.idProduct);
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is working, and I must say that I have never used underscore.js.
Thank you :)

Comment: @Ficho my pleasure. Underscore is a great tool belt. May you mark the question as answered please as well :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var foodList = [
    {

        "userDetails": 

    {

        "id": 27080

    },
    "Items": [

    {

        "ItemDetails": 

        {
            "idProduct": 1420
        },
        "quantity": 1,
        "name": "test1"

    },
    {

        "ItemDetails": 

                {
                    "idProduct": 1959
                },
                "quantity": 5,
                "name": "test2"
            }
        ]

    }
];
var user = [ {
        "id": 1420,
        "name": "test1",
        "price": 12.50,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "proteins": 50,
        "ch": 60
    }];
```

and your matching code

```js
 var productId = user[0].id;
    for(var i=0; i < foodList[0].Items.length; i++)
    {
       var tempList = foodList[0].Items[i];
        if(tempList.ItemDetails.idProduct == productId)
          console.log("Matched");
        else
             console.log("not matched");
    }
```